# How to modify template in jHipster entity subgenerator for angular2?

Tags: node.js, angular, spring-boot, jhipster

I have got some work to modify default html generated by Jhipster for Angular2 more specifically,i want to modify styles for grid generated by Jhipster for Entity's.
  I have gone through tutorial creating module in Jhispter documentation.
https://jhipster.github.io/modules/creating-a-module/
generator for creating subgenerator is also their **can someone please give me pointers on this problem**?

e.g

> yo jhipster:entity Author

from above command jhipster creates all necessary files at server and client like JPA Entity,REST controller,Service, at client side it creates CRUD UI for Author entity using Angular2(i opted for anular2)

I want to modify client generation Code, i just want to modify HTML templates  which gets generated by jhipster entity sub:generator

Answer (score -1):

you need to run Yarn and start modifying your `author.component.html`
which will automatically refreshed in your Browser.

[https://jhipster.github.io/development/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGZwF.png)

Answer (score -1):

You could also consider using git prior to running the generator and then reverting the server side code once the generator has ran